# How does negative zero works in indexing?

Tags: python-2.7

Negative Zero and Positive Zero returns same letter. How does it actually work in Python? Does Python interpret it as Signed zero?

Code here:

```
string = "love"
print string[-0]
```

Comment: `print -0 == 0`

Comment: Indices >= 0 count from start, indices < 0 count from back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no negative 0 in two's complement integers, which Python and most other systems use.  So negative zero is zero.